# Subtract between two pandas data frame with different length

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to do a subtract between two distinct data frames.

I had try the follow code:

```
df_sw['Apropriacao_total'] = df_sw_ant.merge(df_sw, how='left', right_on=['Data posicao', 'Ativo', 'Data vencimento'],
                left_on=['Data posicao', 'Ativo', 'Data vencimento'])
```

['Apropriacao_conjunta'].sub(['Apropriacao'], axis=1)

Below, the sample data frames sample:

**df_sw** *Cols: 6 rows: 62*

```
   Data_posicao   Ativo Data_vencimento  Apropriacao  Apropriacao_conjunta
0    2017-07-03    RXU7      2017-09-07      -631.17              -631.17
1    2017-07-04    RXU7      2017-09-07      -828.59              -828.59
...
22   2017-07-05    GCQ7      2017-07-31      1820.06              1820.06
...
53   2017-07-18  CNHBRL      2017-09-28      1431.82              1431.82
```

**df_sw_ant** *Cols: 6 rows: 32*

```
     Data_swap Data_posicao   Ativo Data_vencimento  Apropriacao_swap
0   2017-07-03   2017-06-30    RXU7      2017-09-07           -333.66
1   2017-07-04   2017-07-03    RXU7      2017-09-07           -631.17
...
22  2017-07-05   2017-07-04    GCQ7      2017-07-31            720.06
...
29  2017-07-20   2017-07-19  CNHBRL      2017-09-28           -157.30
```

**Question:**
How to perform a subtraction (df_sw['Apropriacao_conjunta'] - df_sw_ant['Apropriacao_swap']) where:

`df_sw['Data_posicao'] = df_sw_ant['Data_swap']` and `df_sw['Ativo'] = df_sw_ant['Ativo']` and `df_sw['Data_vencimento'] = df_sw_ant['Data_vencimento']`

**The subtraction will be done in the axis = 1**

Answer (score 0):

You can try following and see if it works for you:

```
# merge and save to new dataframe
df_merged = df_sw_ant.merge(df_sw, how='left', right_on=['Data posicao', 'Ativo', 'Data vencimento'],
            left_on=['Data posicao', 'Ativo', 'Data vencimento'])

# save subtracted result to a new column
df_merged['Sub_Value'] = df_merged['Apropriacao_conjunta'] - df_merged['Apropriacao']
```

Then, `Sub_Value` column in `df_merged` will have the result from subtraction of two columns.